# Alterar o texto dentro de um elemento <span> gerado dinamicamente sem destruir os elemento aninhados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Minha necessidade no primeiro momento parece básica, mas não consigo encontrar uma forma de alterar o texto dentro de uma *tag* `<span>` que é gerada dinamicamente.

Abaixo segue o trecho do DOM na qual eu tenho o seguinte trecho: `<span>Novo Teste</span>`. Preciso simplesmente alterar o texto contido dentro da tag, mas sem destruir os elementos aninhados.

```
<li id="0"><span>Novo Teste</span><span class="acoes"> <a href="#" type="reset" class="btn btn-success edit-item" style="position: relative; top: -1px;"> <span class="entypo-pencil"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Editar </a>
    <a id="$('#destination-service-dropdown option:selected').text()" href="#" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger del-item" style="position: relative; top: -1px;"> <span class="entypo-cancel-squared"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancelar</a>
    </span>
</li>
```

Uma tentativa sem sucesso foi essa:

```
$("#"+idOfListItems+"").next().text($('#destination-service-dropdown option:selected').text());
```

Comment: Testa .find('span') em vez de .next()

Comment: Sergio, alterei para o seguinte `$("#"+idOfListItems+"").find('span').text($('#destination-service-dropdown option:selected').text());`, mas infelizmente não funcionou. Ele alterou o texto dos dois ***span's** e retirou meus botões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolveria da seguinte maneira:

```
var contSpan = $('li#'+idOfListItems).find('span');
$(contSpan[0]).html($('#destination-service-dropdown option:selected').text());
```

Testei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Perfeito Yuri! Funcionou certinho.

Comment: Se quiser da pra melhorar o código, tava dando uma olhada aqui.
`$('li#'+idOfListItems).find('span').eq(0).html($('#destination-service-dropdown option:selected').text());`